# Libraries from system folder does not load correct language

Tags: php, codeigniter, system

I have set two languages in codeigniter, it works fine in my libraries, models and other files.

I have two folders in application/language/ english and french, and I put in witch one form_validation_lang.php take from system/language

I use form_validation library from system whitch load the language file like this

```
$this->CI->lang->load('form_validation')
```

It not have the second parameter and it load just the english language file from application/language/english/ witch is default language.

How can I pass current language to Form_validation.php from system/libraries or how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Load it with second param which is actual language:

```
$this->lang->load('form_validation', $language);
// or like this if you get instance of CI
$this->CI->lang->load('form_validation', $language);
```

where $language is a variable holding currently used language.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. In my controller I put this line

```
$this->lang->load('form_validation', $language);
```

before

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules (......)
```

and now it works.

You have right deczo, but you dont tell me where to put this line.